# clicking submit button appends content to the dom for a few seconds then vanishes

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a list type todo App. The code works fine up to a point. when I click on my submit button the list item is created and it can be briefly seen on the page after which it disappears. Here is my HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script> 
    
       
</head>

<body>
   <h1>My shopping list</h1>
   <form class="form-control">
    <div>
      <label for="text">Enter a new item</label>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="123" >
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul id="11"></ul>
   
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the javacript file

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const list = document.querySelector('ul')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  const myData = input.value
  input.value = ''

  const newdiv = document.createElement('div')
  newdiv.classList.add('newdiv'); 

  const listInput = document.createElement('li')

  const textdata = document.createElement('span')
  textdata.textContent = myData;

  const delButton = document.createElement('button')
  delButton.textContent = 'delete';
  
  listInput.appendChild(textdata)
  newdiv.appendChild(listInput)
  newdiv.appendChild(delButton)

  list.appendChild(newdiv)

  delButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    list.removeChild(listInput)
  })


})
```

hopefully someone can tell me what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please see preventDefault and keep the `form` tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

```
button.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
e.preventDefault()

//code...

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, reformatted my code and it works

Answer (score 1):

Without form your code works because form is not send on button click.

as @Jack said, add event.preventDefault() to button click event to prevent form submit.

See code below

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const list = document.querySelector('ul')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

button.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
  event.preventDefault();
  const myData = input.value
  input.value = ''

  const newdiv = document.createElement('div')
  newdiv.classList.add('newdiv'); 

  const listInput = document.createElement('li')

  const textdata = document.createElement('span')
  textdata.textContent = myData;

  const delButton = document.createElement('button')
  delButton.textContent = 'delete';
  
  listInput.appendChild(textdata)
  newdiv.appendChild(listInput)
  newdiv.appendChild(delButton)

  list.appendChild(newdiv)

  delButton.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    list.removeChild(listInput)
  })


})
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="/script.js" defer></script> 
    
       
</head>

<body>
   <h1>My shopping list</h1>
   <form class="form-control">
    <div>
      <label for="text">Enter a new item</label>
      <input type="text" name="text" id="123" >
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <ul id="11"></ul>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the `<form></form>` tag and it works as expected